# Inserting a semicolon if the next line matches a pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I've been really struggling with the following problem. I have approximately 800 files with this format that I've been trying to write a sed/awk script to fix.

The file will look like the following

```
symbols
    V2:1.2
    v1:1.1
locks; strict;
```

Basically, I need to transform it to add a semicolon to the last line of symbols if the next line contains the word `locks; strict;`.

The output should look like

```
symbols
    V2:1.2
    v1:1.1;
locks; strict;
```

Comment: `sed 'N;/\nlocks; strict;/{s/\n/;&/};P;D'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `N` command to load the next line into pattern space, and if the pattern contains `locks; strict;` after the newline, insert a semicolon before the newline:

```
$ sed 'N;s/\n.*locks;.*strict.*/;&/;P;D' infile
symbols
    V2:1.2
    v1:1.1;
locks; strict;
```

The regular expression for the line with `locks; strict;` is written such that it matches no matter what there is between the two words (or before and after), for example `word locks; more words strict; even more words`. If it should match only if the line contains exactly `locks; strict;`, the command has to be changed to

```
sed 'N;s/\nlocks; strict/;&/;P;D' infile
```

`&` repeats the complete match, so we don't even need capture groups here. The `N;P;D` sequence is the idiomatic way to keep two lines at a time in pattern space: load next line, print up to newline, delete up to newline.

Comment: This won't work for non even lines... People upvote far too early.

Comment: @123 Oops... updated.

Comment: @123 And why didn't you post your answer as, well, an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: Because it's a duplicate and i can't be bothered to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk '/locks; strict;/{l=l";"}NR>1{print l}{l=$0}END{print l}' file
```

Better explained in multiline version:

```
# script.awk

# If the pattern matches we append an ; to the last line (l)
/locks; strict;/ {
    last = last";"
}

# If NR is greater than 1 print the last line.
# Note that in the first line, `last` is still undefined
# at this point.
NR>1 {
    print last
}

# Set last line to current line
{ last = $0 }

# At the end of input print the last line
END {print last}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another `awk` way would be :

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\nlocks; strict\n";ORS=";\nlocks; strict\n"}{print}' your_file
```

Yet another `awk` way to do it :

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="^$"}{$0=gensub(/\nlocks; strict\n/,";\nlocks; strict\n","g",$0); printf "%s",$0}' your_file
```